# How to get the row number of another page in datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the datatable jquery plugin. datatable have more than 3 page.If i want to refresh the 4th row in first page. but currently i am in 3 page.I want to take the current row index using id and refresh the particular row.

```
var rowNum = $('.dataTable1').dataTable().fnGetPosition(document.getElementById("row"+rowId));
```

I used this code to get the row index.It is shown the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null"

How to get the row number of another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DataTables 1.10.x you can do this:

```
var index = $('.dataTable1').DataTable().row('#row'+rowId).index();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
oTable = $('.dataTable1').dataTable();
var nodes = oTable.fnGetNodes();
var row = $(nodes).filter( '#row' + rowId );
var pos = oTable.fnGetPosition( row );
```

Comment: it return "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined" error

Comment: Change 3rd line with this. var row = $(nodes).filter( $('#row' + rowId ));

Comment: Try using Api functions. If you are using data table version above 1.10.   var index = $('.dataTable1').DataTable().row('#row'+rowId).index();